# OnPaint method not drawing the rectangle properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint

I have the following paint event (form) that is drawing the rectangle:

```
void LogicSimulationViewerForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 400, 100);
    Graphics c = rtbLogicCode.CreateGraphics();
    c.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), rect);
}
```

The rectangle is shown for a brief moment and then disappears immediately. The rectangle will only show momentarily again when the user resizes the form.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to Dispose() the Pen after using it. Or use a stock pen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the [Control.CreateGraphics()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics.aspx) method, use the [PaintEventArgs.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.painteventargs.graphics.aspx) property:

```
void LogicSimulationViewerForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 400, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
}
```

Comment: Worked Fantastically. Thanks.